# How to know what select option user has selected

Tags: php

I have actually used to SQLs to find out how many users are there and what property privileges are there in following way:

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli($sql_details['host'],$sql_details['user'],$sql_details['pass'],$sql_details['db']);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        $_SESSION['db_conn_error']=1;
    else
    {
        $query = "select id,username, type from passwords where active=1 and type != 'S'";
        if ($users = $mysqli->query($query))
        {
            $noofusers = mysqli_num_rows($users);   
            $query = "select property_name from privileges";
            if ($noofusers > 0 && $privs = $mysqli->query($query))
            {
                $noofprop = mysqli_num_rows($privs);
                if($noofprop > 0)
                {
                    echo '<table class="tg">';
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<th class="tg-s6z2"> UserName </th>';
                    foreach($privs as $priv)
                    {
                        echo '<th class="tg-s6z2">' . $priv['property_name']. '</th>';
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                    foreach($users as $user)
                    {
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td class="tg-031e">' . $user['username'] . '</td>';
                        for($index =0 ; $index < $noofprop; $index ++)
                        {   
                            echo '<td><select>';
                            echo '<option value="C">Create</option>';
                            echo '<option value="I">Insert</option>';
                            echo '<option value="R">Modify</option>';
                            echo '<option value="V">View</option>';
                            echo '<option value="A">All</option>';
                            echo '</select></td>';
                        }
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                    echo '</table>';

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code successfully creates the below table in my browser:

[image]

So each user has now a option to Create / Delete / Modify / View or All functionalities.

Now this page I would be showing to a superuser only.

The issue is that I am not able to capture for which user which property has been changed or set after page is shown?

Please let me know how I can achieve the same

**EDIT**

After making  the changes as mentioned in comments the form posts data to backend in below manner:

```
select-amrit778 C
select-amrit778 C
select-amrit778 C
select-data C
select-data C
select-data R
select-sss  C
select-sss  R
select-sss  A
```

Is there a way I can POST the priv [column names] along with these?

Comment: you looking for a <form>?

Comment: Let me try using the form element

Comment: Name your select tags **echo '<td><select name="select-' . $user['username'] . '-' . $index . '">';**

Comment: Thanks - but then the order or users privilege stored in database is important as the form post methods sends data in same way - can form post data be send along with what property values also?

Comment: I changed the for($index =0 ; $index < $noofprop; $index ++) by foreach($privs as $priv) with select name including users and priv. This trick seems to have solve the issue but is there a better way than this?